# how to get ID Value from sqlite database (android studio java)

Tags: java, android, string, int, return-value

when i try to click some name from listview, i want it to return the ID from its name(in Toast Text), but i always getting result "0" wherever i click a name in listview, can you help me fix my code?, thanks

MainActivity.java

```
public void toastMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void toastMessageInt(int message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void refreshPage() {
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor getView = myDB.showListView();

    while (getView.moveToNext()) {
        arrayList.add(getView.getString(1));
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            int data = myDB.GetId(name);
            String dataToString = String.valueOf(data);
            toastMessage(dataToString); //here always return "0"
        }
    });
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table notepadData(id integer primary key autoincrement, notepad text)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists notepadData");
    onCreate(db);
}

public int GetId(String currentNote) {
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor getNoteId = myDB.rawQuery("select id from notepadData where notepad = '"+currentNote+"'",null);
    return getNoteId.getColumnIndex("id");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`Cursor getNoteId = myDB.rawQuery("select id from notepadData where notepad like + "'" + currentNote + "'", null);`

Edit:
Wait...now I've noticed what you return...
`getColumnIndex()` returns you index of certain column, where your `id` column is always 0 and it won't change.
You create table with two columns: `id` (index 0) and `notepad` (index 1)
You should use `cursor.getInt(0)` and before that call `cursor.moveToFirst()`
Do it like this:

```
    if (getNoteId != null && getNoteId.moveToFirst() {
       return getNoteId.getInt(0)
    } else {
       return null;  // because you have to return something
    }
```

Comment: excuse me sir, how if "currentNote" have same name from each other, it's return same ID value wherever i click on that name, can you help me with this please

Comment: what i know is just add, "and id = '"+id+"'" behind "currentNote", but i don't know how to get the ID

Comment: When you click on "name" `Cursor` will get you all "id's" with this value. Now you just use `cursor.getInt(0)` so you get only first of them. You can get all values by loop (for example `do-while` or `for`). Otherwise if you really want the certain "id" for certain "name" then you can add another identifier (column) to database which will help you to distinguish fields and it won't be visible to users.